# Using friend functions to retrieve type information from a polymorphic class?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a question about using friend functions inside a nested polymorphic class to retrieve type information.

I have the following code which demonstrates what I'm doing. Given two classes, `A<T>` and `B<T>`, I can create a runtime polymorphic wrapper that holds an `A` or `B`. In practice, this wrapper could hold anything, including another templated class that has a similar static interface.

```
template<typename T>
struct A {
  T value_;

  A(T value) : value_(value) {}

  void sayHello() const {
    std::cout << "Hello from A! " << value_ << '\n';
  }
};

template<typename T>
struct B {
  T value_;

  B(T value) : value_(value) {}

  void sayHello() const {
    std::cout << "Hello from B! " << value_ << '\n';
  }
};
```

The wrapper comes from Sean Parent's Runtime Polymorphism concepts, but I have a need to retrieve the type information for some operations. For example, maybe I can add an `A` and a `B`, but not an `A` and a `C`. Basically, if I place a friend function within the templated wrapper class, I can cast the object back to its original type.

```
class Wrapper {
private:
  class Concept {
  public:
    virtual ~Concept() = default;

    virtual void sayHello() const = 0;
  };

  template<typename T>
  class Model final
      : public Concept {
  private:
    T data_;

  public:
    Model(T data) : data_(data) {}

    virtual void sayHello() const override {
      data_.sayHello();
    }

  private:
    template<typename U>
    friend inline void doSomething(const Concept &lhs, const B<U> &rhs) {
      T x = static_cast<const Model<T> &>(lhs).data_;

      x.sayHello();
      rhs.sayHello();

      auto y = x.value_ + rhs.value_;

      std::cout << y << '\n';
    }
  };

  template<typename U>
  friend inline void doSomething(const Concept &lhs, const B<U> &rhs);

  std::shared_ptr<const Concept> ptr_;

public:
  template<typename T>
  explicit inline Wrapper(T a)
      : ptr_(std::make_shared<Model<A<T>>>(std::move(a))) {}

  template<typename U>
  friend inline void someFriend(Wrapper &lhs, B<U> &rhs) {
    doSomething(*lhs.ptr_, rhs);
  }
};
```

Note that I'm able to `static_cast` the `Concept` class within the friend function because its type can be deduced from within the context of the `Model<T>` class.

So I can use the code like this:

```
Wrapper a(1);
B<int> b{2};

someFriend(a, b);
```

Which outputs:

```
Hello from A! 1
Hello from B! 2
3
```

My question is whether there is some kind of unforeseen problem doing things this way. Also, if I replace the object held in the pointer, should the `static_cast` still work?

Some preliminary tests I've run show that it's fairly reliable, but I occasionally run into the problem that the call seems to 'specialize' around the first object and then doesn't switch if the pointer changes to a new object.

[Here](https://ideone.com/yqOBpH) is a link to the code.

Comment: Why the downvotes? This seems like a legitimate “what is wrong with this” question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are violating the ODR (one definition rule), and hence your code is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

Specifically:

```
template<typename U>
friend inline void doSomething(const Concept &lhs, const B<U> &rhs);
```

there is more than one definition of this; in fact, there is one per `Model<T>`.  By the ODR, there must be one definition of this.

Ill formed, no diagnostic required (IL-NDR) is about the worst thing you can do in C++ standards land.

The symptom you are seeing is some random implementation is invoked, and "sticks".  Nothing at all safe is occuring.

Comment: @solti added it.

Comment: I see. I was assuming there was a single function since the private friend function isn’t a member of Model, right? Is there a way then to use template specialization of the friend function to fix this?

Comment: @Adam Private friend functions aren't members, they are injected into the namespace surrounding the class.  In your case it is strange, because usually friends have to be forward declared or they are unlinked to any outer declarations, but I'm guessing the outer friend and template instantiation order messed with that rule.